# How to publish a video file on the internet to stream it in an app using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, media-player, mp4

I'm using this code to play a video in my IOS app. I want to be able to stream the video, not have it hard copped in. I have the video file, but how do i publish it onto a mp4 webpage to have it streamed in the app? Here is an example video [webpage](http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/MediaCoder/MediaCoder_test1_1m9s_AVC_VBR_256kbps_640x480_24fps_MPEG2Layer3_CBR_160kbps_Stereo_22050Hz.mp4)...

Are there any tools online to help me do this?

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

// add mediaplayer framework

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var movie:MPMoviePlayerViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.






        let movieurl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/MediaCoder/MediaCoder_test1_1m9s_AVC_VBR_256kbps_640x480_24fps_MPEG2Layer3_CBR_160kbps_Stereo_22050Hz.mp4")

        if movieurl != nil {

        self.movie = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: movieurl!)

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func playTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        if self.movie != nil {

        self.presentViewController(self.movie!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.movie?.moviePlayer.play()


        }

    }

}
```